# Почему вылетает ошибка $C0000005

Tags: delphi

```
program lab2v2;
// Данная программа сравнивает шейкерную сортировку и
// сортировку бинарными вставками по количеству
// присваиваний

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TArray = array [1 .. 3000] of integer;
  TDateArray = array [1 .. 6] of integer;

  { TBaseOfArray - базовый типа массива
    TArray - тип-массив }

const
  ArrLength: TDateArray = (100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000);

  { ArrLength - массив, хранящий длины массивов }


  // Процедура, меняющая местами элементы массива Element1
  // и Element2

  { Element1, Element2 - две элемента массива, меняющиеся местами }

procedure Swap(var Element1, Element2: integer);
var
  Temp: integer;

  { Temp - переменная для хранения одного из элементов при замене }

begin
  Temp := Element1;
  Element1 := Element2;
  Element2 := Temp;
end;


// Шейкерная сортировка

{ NumberOfSwaps - число перестановок
  Arr - сортируемый массив }

function CoctailSort(var Arr: TArray; var kol: integer): integer;
var
  i, Left, Right, NumberOfSwaps: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла
    Left, Right - левая и правая границы в шейкерной
    сортировке
    LastSwap - место последнего обмена для более быстрого
    сужения границ }

begin
  NumberOfSwaps := 0;
  Left := 1;
  Right := kol;
  while Left < Right do
  begin
    // Проход слева направо
    for i := Left to Right - 1 do
      if Arr[i] > Arr[i + 1] then
      begin
        Swap(Arr[i], Arr[i + 1]);
        Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 1);
      end;

    // Проход справа налево
    for i := Right downto Left + 1 do
      if Arr[i] < Arr[i - 1] then
      begin
        Swap(Arr[i], Arr[i - 1]);
        Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 1);
      end;

    // Сдвиг левой границы вправо
    Left := Left + 1;
    Right := Right + 1;
  end;
  CoctailSort := NumberOfSwaps;
end;

// Сортировка бинарными вставками

{ NumberOfSwaps - число перестановок
  Arr - сортируемый массив }

function BinaryInsertSort(var Arr: TArray; var kol: integer): integer;
var
  i, j, Left, Right, Middle, NumberOfSwaps, Temp: integer;

  { i, j - счётчики циклов
    Left, Right - левая и правая границы в сортировке
    бинарными вставками
    Middle - середина рассматриваемого отрезка массива в
    сортировке
    Temp - переменнаяя для хранения вставляемого элемента }

begin
  NumberOfSwaps := 0;
  for i := 2 to kol do
  begin
    Left := 1;
    Right := i-1;
    Temp := Arr[i];

    // Поиск позиции для вставляемого элемента методом
    // бинарного поиска
    repeat

      Middle := (Left + Right) div 2;
      if Arr[Middle]<temp then
       Left := Middle + 1
      else
        Right := Middle-1;
    until left>right;

    // Сдвиг элементов вправо
    for j := i-1 downto Left do
    begin
      Arr[j+1] := Arr[j];
      Inc(NumberOfSwaps);
    end;

    // Вставляем элемент
    Arr[left] := temp;
    Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 2);
  end;
  BinaryInsertSort:=NumberOfSwaps;
end;


// Заполнение массива Arr случайными значениями

{ Arr - заполняемый массив
  MaxNumber - максимальный возможный элемент массива }

procedure RandomFill(var Arr: TArray; kol:integer);
var
  i: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла }

begin
  Randomize;
  for i := 1to kol do
    // Элемент массива инициализируется случайным
    // натуральным числом не больше MaxNumber
    Arr[i] := Random(kol)+1;
end;


// Переворачивание массива

{ Arr - переворачиваемый массив }

procedure Reverse(var Arr: TArray; kol:integer);
var
  i: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла }

begin
  for i := 1 to kol div 2 do
    Swap(Arr[i], Arr[kol - i +1]);
end;


// Основной алгоритм

var
  i, j, Swaps,N,res: integer;
  Arr: TArray;
  MaxElement: integer;
  CoctailSwaps: array [1 .. 3,1..6] of integer;
  InsertSwaps: array [1 .. 3,1..6] of integer;
  ErrorString: String;
  ErrorCode: integer;
  ErrorFlag: Boolean;

  { i, j - счётчики цикла
    Swaps - количество перестановок
    Arr - сортируемый массив
    CoctailSwaps - массив, хранящий количество
    перестановок в шейкерной сортировке для массивов
    разных размеров
    InsertSwaps - массив, хранящий количество перестановок
    в сортировке бинарными вставками для массивов разных
    размеров }

begin
  // Заполнение массивов, хранящих перестановки, нулями
  // FillChar заполняет 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray) байт в
  // CoctailSwaps значениями 0
  FillChar(CoctailSwaps, 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray), 0);
  FillChar(InsertSwaps, 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray), 0);

  for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    N:=ArrLength[i];

    // Измеряем количество перестановок 3 раза и находим среднее
    for j := 1 to 2 do
    begin
      (* Шейкерная сортировка *)

      // Сортировка случайного массива

      RandomFill(Arr, N);
      res:=CoctailSort(Arr, N);
      Inc(CoctailSwaps[1][i], res);

      (* Бинарные вставки *)

      // Сортировка случайного массива
      RandomFill(Arr, N);
      res:=BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
      Inc(InsertSwaps[1][i], res);
    end;

    (* Шейкерная сортировка *)

    // Сортировка случайного массива

      RandomFill(Arr, N);
      res:=CoctailSort(Arr, N);
      Inc(CoctailSwaps[1][i], res);

    // Сортировка отсортированного массива
    res:= CoctailSort(Arr, N);
    CoctailSwaps[2][i]:=res;

    // Сортировка перевернутого массива

    Reverse(Arr,N);
    res:=CoctailSort(Arr, N);
    CoctailSwaps[3][i]:=res;

    (* Бинарные вставки *)

    // Сортировка случайного массива
    RandomFill(Arr, N);
    res:=BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    Inc(InsertSwaps[1][i], res);

    // Сортировка отсортированного массива
    res:=BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    InsertSwaps[2][i]:=res;
    // Сортировка перевернутого массива
    Reverse(Arr,N);
    res:=BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    InsertSwaps[3][i]:=res;

    CoctailSwaps[1][i] := CoctailSwaps[1][i] div 3;
    InsertSwaps[1][i] := InsertSwaps[1][i] div 3;
  end;

 // Вывод результатов
 {Код вывода}
```

end.

Comment: В функции CoctaliSort ты увеличиваешь как левую, так и правую границу. Причём, не проверяешь на выход за пределы массива. В определённый момент правая граница становится больше длины массива TArray.

Comment: @OldSkull да, увидел, дома проверю